# Crypt32 function CryptProtectData always returning "\x1"

Tags: c, crypt

Trying to use the Crypt32 functions CryptProtectData and CryptUnprotectData to encrypt and decrypt strings from a C program.  The encrypt claims to be successful, but the pbData in the output DATA_BLOB always contains just "\x1". Below is what I am currently using for encryption.  Any suggestions on what I may be doing wrong?

This is on Windows 7 using crypt32.dll v6.1.7601.

```
EXPORT short CALLBACK ASEncryptDPApiValue (char *pszEntropy, char *pszValue, char *pszEncryptValue, int iValueLen)
{
   short sRetCd = 0;
   char szDecryptValue [MAX_INI_VALUE] = "";
   DWORD dwLastErrorRC = 0;
   DWORD dwFlags = CRYPTPROTECT_LOCAL_MACHINE;
   CHAR szMsgBuffer[200] = "";

   DATA_BLOB encrBlob;
   DATA_BLOB decrBlob = {0, 0};
   DATA_BLOB entropyBlob = {0, 0};
   LPWSTR pDescrOut =  NULL;

   if (pszValue[0] != '\0')
      {
      decrBlob.pbData = (BYTE *)pszValue;
      decrBlob.cbData = strlen((char *)decrBlob.pbData)+1;
      }
   // else return an error

   if (pszEntropy[0] != '\0')
      {
      entropyBlob.pbData = (BYTE *)pszEntropy;
      entropyBlob.cbData = strlen((char *)entropyBlob.pbData)+1;
      }

   if (CryptProtectData(&decrBlob,
                        pDescrOut,
                        &entropyBlob, 
                        NULL,
                        NULL,
                        dwFlags,
                        &encrBlob))
      {
      strcpy_s(pszEncryptValue, iValueLen, (char *) encrBlob.pbData);
      dwLastErrorRC = GetLastError();
      LocalFree(encrBlob.pbData);
      sprintf(szMsgBuffer, 
         _T("ASEncryptDPApiValue - Decrypting value - successful = %d  [%s]\r\n"), dwLastErrorRC, pszEncryptValue);
      OutputDebugString(szMsgBuffer);
      }
   else
      {
      sRetCd = TRUE;
      dwLastErrorRC = GetLastError();
      sprintf(szMsgBuffer, 
         _T("ASEncryptDPApiValue - error decrypting value - last OS error = %d\r\n"), dwLastErrorRC);
      OutputDebugString(szMsgBuffer);
      LocalFree(encrBlob.pbData);
      }

    return sRetCd;
}
```

Comment: According to the snippet, you only encrypt a string (`CryptProtectData`) then you're trying to print it. The encrypted string is **binary** (meaning that it's not suitable to be used by the `NULL` terminated strings function families (e.g. `strcpy_s` or `sprintf`) as it may contain `\0`s; that's the reason why the `DATA_BLOB` structure has the `cbData` member). Also, no need to call `GetLastError` when a function succeeds. Pass `encrBlob` to `CryptUnprotectData` and only then try printing the result.

Comment: Description of the problem was incomplete and I left the clutter in the code sample include.  I wound up converting the binary to base64 in order to store and retrieve from a file.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Good to hear you worked things up. Note: *base64* is not mandatory in order to save some data in files, the files can be opened as *binary*.